# Atom Install - error. 'osascript' could not be spawned

Tags: ide, installation, atom-editor

I want to start use IDE Atom at home, and I faced with problem:

> 'osascript' could not be spawned.  Is it installed and on your path? 
>   If so please open an issue on the  package spawning the process.

Couldn't find right answer. Does someone can help me with it?

Comment: Are you on a mac? Can you open a terminal and run `which osascript` and paste the result here?

Comment: @EhrenMurdick no. Win10

Comment: Oh, that's... weird. osascript is a mac specific tool, for running applescript. Did you build it yourself, or download a zip of a release? You sure you downloaded the correct release?

Comment: @EhrenMurdick Yes. I downloaded windows 64bit version, just save it on my local storage, installed and run and saw this error.

Comment: Do you have `atomify` package installed? If that's the case, uninstall that - it only works on Macs.